# Align/copy sections of 2D numpy array according to indices in second array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays.

Array #1 is called `idx`, has only integers, has shape (Nx5), and contains "sections" of data that are organized according to the first index in every row. I.e., the full array may have 10,000 rows, and there could be 1000 rows where the value at the first index is 1. These 1000 rows then collectively represent the data of "block 1" or "section 1".

Array #2 (lets call it `arr2`) is an array whose entries correspond to the different "sections" from `idx`. I.e., if `arr2` was `array([1,1,1,2,6])`, the first 3 entries correspond to the data contained in section 1 of `idx`, the 4th entry corresponds to section 2, the last entry corresponds to all the data in section 6.

My question is what is the fastest way to create a new 2D numpy array that contains the blocks from `idx` repeated according to the order in `arr2`. The zero order solution would be something like:

```
blocks = []
for i in arr2:
    mask = idx == i
    block = idx[mask]
    blocks.append(block)

blocks = np.array(blocks)
```

Is there a way to be faster? Recalculating the mask seems wasteful.

Edit:

More information on the `idx` array. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK4QV.png) is a picture from a Jupyter notebook with some some simple statistics and a slice from one of my `idx` arrays. For what it's worth, `idx` is actually used downstream to build a 5D tensor with `tf.scatter_nd`.

Edit 2:

A random sample of 100 rows from `idx`. You should be able to copy paste this into a script and create the array.

```
idx_sample = np.array([ [457,3,9,7,46] ,
[409,11,2,2,48] ,
[193,14,21,8,50] ,
[38,12,7,9,46] ,
[35,5,13,0,3] ,
[87,7,13,11,67] ,
[144,14,10,12,13] ,
[370,20,9,17,82] ,
[338,19,14,8,50] ,
[55,15,17,11,19] ,
[118,7,18,8,90] ,
[273,22,8,12,71] ,
[44,15,23,18,75] ,
[459,4,5,9,39] ,
[341,23,5,5,48] ,
[167,8,2,10,13] ,
[21,3,9,11,46] ,
[451,4,20,8,34] ,
[368,13,23,15,90] ,
[386,15,7,17,58] ,
[250,8,5,6,12] ,
[84,8,10,10,28] ,
[376,16,6,1,93] ,
[91,11,20,5,45] ,
[119,13,2,6,87] ,
[215,15,2,14,80] ,
[435,21,13,3,38] ,
[106,14,21,1,45] ,
[145,23,12,1,49] ,
[84,11,22,20,92] ,
[436,19,14,2,30] ,
[384,11,18,18,57] ,
[121,2,5,12,7] ,
[445,18,21,11,92] ,
[354,21,12,0,9] ,
[365,22,12,21,89] ,
[140,19,1,15,86] ,
[280,20,14,1,74] ,
[363,1,17,18,16] ,
[312,2,18,9,72] ,
[273,20,3,11,52] ,
[265,13,5,17,47] ,
[465,4,7,22,16] ,
[447,12,12,14,102] ,
[12,14,7,10,65] ,
[115,8,23,13,10] ,
[267,16,17,11,6] ,
[1,16,14,7,63] ,
[61,17,8,11,7] ,
[226,3,10,4,58] ,
[267,3,1,5,47] ,
[186,11,19,1,27] ,
[465,9,8,22,65] ,
[71,9,5,3,19] ,
[369,11,21,2,91] ,
[70,2,23,10,48] ,
[196,8,19,8,48] ,
[385,7,1,14,34] ,
[141,5,16,12,48] ,
[439,3,5,19,94] ,
[339,17,18,18,30] ,
[383,18,18,11,84] ,
[160,15,19,10,18] ,
[234,11,11,14,102] ,
[174,17,10,23,11] ,
[125,5,3,1,11] ,
[139,8,15,8,85] ,
[208,22,4,15,47] ,
[132,15,15,0,49] ,
[458,18,23,9,68] ,
[68,12,7,9,36] ,
[263,3,4,16,48] ,
[362,8,7,0,13] ,
[330,3,20,18,98] ,
[104,14,16,22,97] ,
[200,12,13,2,98] ,
[357,18,23,6,11] ,
[145,23,14,13,11] ,
[204,10,21,10,56] ,
[28,12,9,6,31] ,
[226,16,7,13,10] ,
[436,3,22,12,89] ,
[257,16,12,11,31] ,
[243,17,6,12,88] ,
[349,21,8,13,58] ,
[258,22,7,2,99] ,
[458,4,1,13,32] ,
[359,19,19,2,69] ,
[343,6,9,4,28] ,
[194,4,2,21,47] ,
[13,14,3,3,80] ,
[328,23,3,11,65] ,
[467,10,15,14,71] ,
[257,16,23,4,91] ,
[206,14,9,13,48] ,
[418,0,17,6,27] ,
[373,20,23,3,14] ,
[27,3,5,23,67] ,
[437,22,16,4,54] ,
[468,17,8,21,45] ])
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of `idx`?

Comment: @DavidErickson Just updated with a picture! Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks, kindly include that as text in your question so I don't have type to out.

Comment: @DavidErickson Okay provided some code to create a sample of `idx`!